# PostgreSQL - Where to store owners data?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

It is ok to store the owners (the ones who access the main project dashboards) in the same database schema where normal users are stored? If so, how it is best: in the same "users" table with a flag "role" or in an independent table "owners".

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE owners (
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    role INT NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to store the users in one table.

Here is why:

- One table storing very similar kind of data
- It's easier to upgrade a user to a superuser
- Maintenance
- Follow up sql statements using users will be less complex

Comment: I see the same advantages but I had doubts about storing the owners data in the same table.

Comment: This is quite common, the table should be only accessible by the application anyways. So if someone has access to it, it will be even easier for him if you create an own table named "owners" :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that having only one table is easier to maintain and simplifies the logic of the app. The "role" field allows future expansion in case you'd like to add new role types. Security-wise, having one or two tables should be very similar. But it depends of how you access the table, permissions, ...
I'm not sure this answer is very helpful, but we would need a bit more of context to be able to help you further...